# jquery dropdown vertical menu responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to build a vertical menu, not sure I'm chosen the right way though!

Menu on click should show!  if I click another menu the previous menu should hide!
Please check my demo, the menu doesn't close the previous.

demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/5uWh2/

JS:

```
var dropdown = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown');
var dropdownArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(dropdown,0);


dropdownArray.forEach(function(el){
    var button = el.querySelector('a[data-toggle="dropdown-text"]'),
            menu = el.querySelector('.dropdown-content');

    button.onclick = function(event) {
    if(!menu.hasClass('show')) {
            menu.classList.add('show');
            menu.classList.remove('hide');
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        else {
      menu.classList.remove('show');
            menu.classList.add('hide');
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    };
})

Element.prototype.hasClass = function(className) {
  return this.className && new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + className + "(\\s|$)").test(this.className);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this in following way

```
$( "#menu a" ).click(function() {
   $menu = $(this).parent().find('ul');           
   $('#menu').find('ul').not($menu).removeClass('show');
   $menu.toggleClass('show');
});
```

[Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/sameer_kc/5uWh2/37/)

Comment: thanks, nice one, why the else{} doesn't work? it should close if I click the opened one

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#menu > li > a').click(function(){
    if(jQuery(this).next('.dropdown-content').length>0){
      jQuery('.dropdown-content').slideUp();
      if(jQuery(this).next('.dropdown-content:visible').size()){
       jQuery('.dropdown-content').slideUp();
      } else {
        jQuery(this).next('.dropdown-content').slideDown();
      }
      return false;
    }
      });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5py85/1/

Comment: I like it, but I prefer to use css, so adding classes. could u update your answer by adding classes?